# How to start a service again after the app has been minimized and then opened again?

Tags: java, android, service, minimize

I have a problem with a service in android. it works fine when the app has started, but if the app is minimized, and the service is destroyed i can't start the service again when i re open the app.

Here is the oncreate and onstart in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    //Activates the custom toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle navigationDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(navigationDrawerToggle);
    navigationDrawerToggle.syncState();

    //Checks first item in the navigation drawer initially
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.fragment_camera);

    //Open camera fragment initially when the app starts.
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentInterface = new FotoapparatFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragmentInterface);
    }

    setupConnectionToService();

    Intent backgroundReceiptService = new Intent(this, ReceiptService.class);
    startService(backgroundReceiptService);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiptService.class);
    bindService(intent, receiptConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d(MAIN_LOG, "Binded With ReceiptService");
}
```

Here is the onStartCommand in the service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    receiptDatabase = ReceiptDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    //Checks if the permission to use external storage on the phone has been granted
    if (PermissionUtil.checkPermission(getApplicationContext(), PermissionUtil.Permissions.EXTERNAL_READ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        callLatestReceiptData(null);
        initializeFileObserver();
        listInitialized = true;
    }

    //TODO: Needs to moved elsewhere, but are not sure where
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Period period = new Period();
            period.setMPeriodId(1);
            receiptDatabase.daoAccessPeriod().insertNewPeriod(period);
        }
    }).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: what has this got to do with re-starting an app? minimizing it is not the same as terminating it

Comment: No but the onDestroy in the service is called when the app has been minimized long enough, and then i can't seem to start the service again when i open the app from it's minimized state

Answer (score 0):

use ServiceConnection.

```
playerIntent = new Intent(ActPlayMusic.this, MusicPlayerService.class);

                    startService(playerIntent);
                    bindService(playerIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


  private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            MusicPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
            try {
                playerService = binder.getServiceInstance();
                playerService.registerClient(ActPlayMusic.this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
    }
};




 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
          bindService(playerIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: i have done that, but the onCreate in my activity is not called again after the app has been minimized and opened again, but onStart is, but it is in the oncreate i am using the ServiceConnection.

Comment: UPDATE: i can see through debugging, that the service is being connected again through the serviceConnection and the service is binded again, but the onStartCommand in the service is never called

Answer (score 0):

OK So In your in your Service class you need to override onStartCommand() and return the flag START_STICKY This should restart your service. For more info visit visit the Android developer page on this topic of Services.

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,0,START_STICKY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start service from background, right? I have used this method to accomplish my tracking requirement.

You can user [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) along with [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).Use `return Service.START_STICKY` on **onStartCommand** in service.

In **onDestroy** or in **onTaskRemoved** you can write send start broadcast receiver as below[in kotlin].

```
override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    Log.e("Api service on Task Removed Send Location Service")
    if (Global.getPreference(Constant.IS_USER_LOGIN, false)!!) {
        val broadcastIntent = Intent("com.myapp.project.restartSendLocationService")
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
    }
}
```

And in receiver you can start your service again as below [in kotlin].

```
class SendLocationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(_context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if (_context != null) {
        val context = _context.applicationContext
        val intentDemo = Intent(_context.applicationContext, SendLocationService::class.java)
        Log.e("Smart Sales", "UpdateLocationService \$status")
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startService(intentDemo)
            } else {
                context.startForegroundService(intentDemo)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Smart Sales", e.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

}

Don't forget to add  in manifest.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ServiceStuff.kotlin.SendLocationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myapp.project.restartSendLocationService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Note : In some custom OS service does not run in background.